# Im trying to export an excel file to pdf but alignment is going off?

Tags: vb.net, excel, formatting, automation, export-to-pdf

When exporting the sheet the alignment goes off.
half data goes on next line.
How can i alignment the sheet programmatically and convert it to pdf without alignment going off.

I need something like fit to page.

Comment: Have you tried to record a macro for the same manual steps as you wish? In Print Preview mode you may align your data and set page orientation.

Answer (score 0):

The width of PDF depend on you Excel print setting, at default, it will set to A4 portrait, so the export PDF will leave the half data to next line; if you set the paper size to A3 Landscape, then export to PDF, it will show the correct format.

Answer (score 0):

i have experienced same problem, so what i did:

1. for the excel file sheet i set the following

   ```
           xlWorkbook = xlApps.Workbooks.Add(missing);
           xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkbook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
           xlApps.ActiveWindow.View = Excel.XlWindowView.xlPageLayoutView; //pagelayout view
           xlWorkSheet.PageSetup.PaperSize = Excel.XlPaperSize.xlPaperA4; //set paper to A4
           xlWorkSheet.PageSetup.Orientation = Excel.XlPageOrientation.xlPortrait; //set to portrait

           //margins 'Narrow'   
           xlWorkSheet.PageSetup.LeftMargin = 0.65; //55
           xlWorkSheet.PageSetup.RightMargin = 0.25;
           xlWorkSheet.PageSetup.BottomMargin = 0.75;
           xlWorkSheet.PageSetup.TopMargin = 0.75; //60
           xlWorkSheet.PageSetup.HeaderMargin = 0;
   ```
2. convert my excel file and scale the size. (just change 120 to fit your document)

   ```
         //here is the scaling
           Worksheet xlmsheet = excelWorkBook.Sheets[1];
           xlmsheet.PageSetup.Zoom = 120; 
            // Save it in the target format.
           if (excelWorkBook != null)
               excelWorkBook.ExportAsFixedFormat(XlFixedFormatType.xlTypePDF, paramExportFilePath, XlFixedFormatQuality.xlQualityStandard, true,
                   true, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, false, paramMissing);
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use FitToPagesWide and FitToPagesTall

```
    xlWorkSheet.PageSetup.Zoom = False
    xlWorkSheet.PageSetup.FitToPagesWide = 1
    xlWorkSheet.PageSetup.FitToPagesTall = 1
```